# XML HTTP Request to execute javascript on target page

Tags: javascript, ajax, include, xmlhttprequest, execute

I am using an XMLHttpRequest function to get data from an external page as selected through a javascript function and then return the results to a DIV container, which works fine until the target page has a Javascript function inside - which is not executed.

code for basic function is here:

```
function haha(url) {
var NRL = url+".php";
var target = "InnerContent";
  document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = ' Fetching page...';
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (req != undefined) {
  evalScripts:true
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {hahaDone(NRL);};
    req.open("GET", NRL, true);
    req.send("");
  }

}  

function hahaDone(url) {
var target = "InnerContent";
var ExtraText = '';
  if (req.readyState == 4) { // only if req is "loaded"
    if (req.status == 200) { // only if "OK"
    evalScripts:true
      document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = req.responseText+ExtraText;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(target).innerHTML=" AJAX Error:\n"+ req.status + "\n"+req.statusText;
    }

 }
}
```

How can this function be amended to execute javascript on the target page to load? I don't really want to start going into Jquery or anything like that as this current code is understandable enough and I've customised it to work for the current site which is suppoed to be going live in just a few hours.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `responseText` is only for textual content. No HTML tag whatsoever.

Comment: Well HTML tags like <B>, <H1>, <A> etc go through with it OK, just ot Javascript commands....

Comment: Check the *Error Console* to see where the error is located.